# Spring Mail shutting down micro service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, microservices

I have a micro service with Spring Boot 2.4.2 that uses JavaMailSender to send emails.
The problem is, if I don't have internet and/or the email configuration is wrong, the micro service register at Eureka Server as DOWN and don't answer my requests. My micro service isn't just for the email and can/need to work without external connection, how do I prevent the email to kill my micro service?

My Properties:

```
## INFORMACOES EMAIL
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connecttimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=Wrong email (For debug porpuses)
spring.mail.password=NOT HERE...
```

Comment: Your issue is not with the type of microservice but registering with the discovery client. Are you saying that your microservice fails to get discovered even when it is up and accepting the calls?

Comment: It get discovered but as a down service. My Eureka Server knows that I have this micro service. If I build the service with everything right and the internet goes off, this only service goes down on the Eureka Server and didn't answer any requests even if it doesn't exactly needs external connection (this service runs in a internal server on my client). If I build the service with the email config wrong, he discovers at Eureka as a Down service and, again, didn't answer any requests

Comment: Are you able to directly invoke the endpoint of your microservice when Eureka shows it as down? Did you check the application port was it active at that time? Also what about the exceptions in the logs?

Comment: I'm able to directly hit the endpoint but, with the mail problem and when the eureka show that it's down, it doesn't answer. My service doesn't have a default port, I'm using an API Gateway for that so I can't check if the port is used but I think it is, cause my API Gateway answers me. The exceptions on the log are only about wrong Mail configuration or that he can't connect at the email server.

Comment: I think I'm gonna need to separate the Email function as a new micro service just to send emails so that way my other functions aren't going to be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that Spring Actuator creates an MailHealthIndicator automtically when you configure a mail sender.

You can disable it setting the propery `management.health.mail.enabled` to `false` in your `application.properties` or the system property or environment variable.

The only thing you want to consider is what you do if the mail service is not reachable, maybe store the request in a database or a queue...